# Continuation monad "interface"

Tags: haskell, monads, continuations, state-monad

The state monad "interface"

```
class MonadState s m where
    get :: m s
    put :: s -> m ()
```

(+ return and bind) allows to construct any possible computation with State monad without using `State` constructor. For example, `State $ \s -> (s+1, s-1)` can be written as

```
 do s <- get
    put (s-1)
    return (s+1)
```

Similarily, I never have to use `Reader` constructor, because I can create that computation using `ask`, `return` and `(>>=)`. Precisely: `Reader f == ask >>= return . f`.

Is it the same true for continuations - is it possible to write all instances of `Cont r a` using `callCC` (the only function in `MonadCont`), return and bind, and never type something like `Cont (\c -> ...)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think so.  Looking at the types:

```
Cont :: ((a -> r) -> r) -> Cont r a
callCC :: ((a -> Cont r b) -> Cont r a) -> Cont r a
```

If you only have `callCC`, there is no use of `r` as a type anywhere - it could be of any kind.  So I don't know how you could translate something that uses it as a type, eg:

```
Cont (const 42) :: Cont Int a
```

I have no way of constraining `r` if I only have `callCC`.

Anyway, that's my hunch. Not terribly rigorous, but it seems convincing.